# binance api function crashes when trying to create margin loans

Tags: python, bitcoin, cryptocurrency, binance

I am writing a function for an api interface to quickly switch between long and short margin positions. I have more than enough funds in the isolated account to avoid the MIN_NOTATIONAL error. The debt and balance do not update after creating orders and this crashes the program when I call the switch() function because the program asks to borrow from an empty account.

When I try to repay the loan using closeLong() and closeShort() a small balance also remains and I cannot figure out why it is because I use the exact amount of debt pulled from the client.get_isolated_margin_account() dictionary.

EDIT: the pair is OCEAN/USDT which is 3x margin, that's why the multiplier for marginBase and marginQuote is 3

Code:

```
isLongOpen = False
acct = client.get_isolated_margin_account()
sym = acct['assets'][1]['symbol']
def getBaseBalance():
    rawBase = round(Decimal(acct['assets'][1]['baseAsset']['free']),2)
    baseBalance = str(rawBase)
    return baseBalance
def getMarginBase():
    rawBase = round(Decimal(acct['assets'][1]['baseAsset']['free']),2)
    marginBase=str(Decimal(3)* rawBase)
    return marginBase
def getQuoteBalance():
    rawQuote = round(Decimal(acct['assets'][1]['quoteAsset']['free']),2)
    baseQuote = str(rawQuote)
    return baseQuote
def getMarginQuote():
    rawQuote = round(Decimal(acct['assets'][1]['quoteAsset']['free']),2)
    marginQuote=str(Decimal(3)* rawQuote)
    return marginQuote

def baseDebt():
    baseLoan = round(Decimal(acct['assets'][1]['baseAsset']['borrowed']),2)
    print("Ocean Debt: "+str(baseLoan))
    return baseLoan
def quoteDebt():
    quoteLoan = round(Decimal(acct['assets'][1]['quoteAsset']['borrowed']),2)
    print("USDT Debt: "+str(quoteLoan))
    return quoteLoan

def checkDebt():
    if baseDebt()!=0:
        print("Short Open")
        isLongOpen = False
        return isLongOpen
    elif quoteDebt()!=0:
        print("Long Open")
        isLongOpen = True
        return isLongOpen

def openLong():
    client.create_margin_order(
        symbol=sym, 
        side= SIDE_BUY, 
        type= ORDER_TYPE_MARKET , 
        sideEffectType= 'MARGIN_BUY', 
        isIsolated='TRUE', 
        quoteOrderQty=getMarginQuote())
    print("Opened Long")

def closeLong():
    client.create_margin_order(
        symbol=sym,
        side=SIDE_SELL,
        type=ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,
        sideEffectType= 'AUTO_REPAY', 
        isIsolated='TRUE',
        quoteOrderQty=quoteDebt())  
    print("Closed Long")

def openShort():
    client.create_margin_order(
        symbol=sym,
        side=SIDE_SELL,
        type=ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,
        sideEffectType= 'MARGIN_BUY', 
        isIsolated='TRUE',
        quantity=getMarginBase())   
    print("Opened Short")

def closeShort():
    client.create_margin_order(
        symbol=sym,
        side=SIDE_BUY,
        type=ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,
        sideEffectType= 'AUTO_REPAY', 
        isIsolated='TRUE',
        quantity=baseDebt())  
    print("Closed Short")

def switch():
    if(checkDebt() == True):
        closeLong()
        print("Base " +getBaseBalance())
        print("Quote "+getQuoteBalance())
        openShort()
        print("Base " +getBaseBalance())
        print("Quote "+getQuoteBalance())
    else:
        closeShort()
        print("Base " +getBaseBalance())
        print("Quote "+getQuoteBalance())
        openLong()
        print("Base " +getBaseBalance())
        print("Quote "+getQuoteBalance())
    
    return isLongOpen
print(sym)
print("Base " +getBaseBalance())
print("Quote "+getQuoteBalance())
print(checkDebt())
print(switch())
print("Base " +getBaseBalance())
print("Quote "+getQuoteBalance())
print("END")
```

This is the output of this code for switching from shorts and switching from longs:

```
OCEANUSDT
Base 39.36
Quote 0.00
Ocean Debt: 0.00
USDT Debt: 39.54
Long Open
True
Ocean Debt: 0.00
USDT Debt: 39.54
Long Open
USDT Debt: 39.54
Closed Long
Base 39.36
Quote 0.00
line 128, in openShort
    client.create_margin_order(
BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-11008): Exceeding the account's maximum borrowable limit.

OCEANUSDT
Base 0.00
Quote 58.42
Ocean Debt: 25.95
Short Open
False
Ocean Debt: 25.95
Short Open
Ocean Debt: 25.95
Closed Short
Base 0.00
Quote 58.42
line 108, in openLong
    client.create_margin_order(
BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-11008): Exceeding the account's maximum borrowable limit.
```

Comment: We don't know what your account's margin limit is.  ARE you exceeding it?

Comment: Any update on this ?